# Oracle Apex 4.2 Tabular Form checkbox for changed column value

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, oracle-apex, tabular

I have an Apex Tabular form:

```
ID Name    Title   Class    ROW_EDIT <br>
1  Smith    Mgr     AP      (checkbox)<br>
```

etc...

I am trying to activate the 'checkbox' `ROW_EDIT` column - which has a default value of `Y` - when the user changes the value for the tabular form column `Class` (Select list) in the same row.  I can change the `ROW_EDIT` attribute to text (ie, `Y`) if easier...

I have no apex_items for the page to reference - all columns are tabular form.

I have researched some dynamic change events - but I can't seem to get the row-reference to set correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, It is possible only with JavaScript code. Is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is OK.  Thank you... any help you can offer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, last time I saw APEX 4.2 was 2 years ago and I don't have it now.
The idea is in the following:

- Add onchange event to select list. I don't remember is there an easy way to do this. If not, you can create a select list manually using `APEX_ITEM` package. To do this, write in the source query:

  ```
  select apex_item.select_list_from_lov (
           p_idx => 10, 
           p_value => class, -- it is a name of a table column
           p_lov => 'my_lov_name', 
           p_attributes => 'onchange="my_func.call(this);"')
    from ...
  ```
- In page properites (`JavaScript` section), create a javascript function:

  ```
  function my_func () {
     this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = true;
  }
  ```

Parameter `this` in the function is a reference to select list. Hence, `this.parentElement.parentElement` - reference to row with the triggering select list, `getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` is a checkbox. If you have several input elements in the row, use proper index instead of `0`.
How this JavaScript code works you can check here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvPmPp